# Create a method for inputting objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods, output

I have a task to create a method which holds the same variables as the already created constructor for my objects whicj i have added 3 of them to the ArrayList.

When the method is called in the main Class, where all my code is, I should write in the () my info that I want to attach to the new object, which later will be added to the ArrayList by the same method.

Below are snippets of my code...

```
public class Joke extends Main {
public String username;
public String email;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String phoneNumber;
public int jokeID;
public String jokeText;

public Joke(String username, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, int jokeID, String jokeText) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.jokeID = jokeID;
    this.jokeText = jokeText;
}
```

and this is the method I came up with

```
public static Joke addJokerToArrayList(String username, String email, String firstName, String lastName,
                                       String phoneNumber, int jokeID, String jokeText) {
    Joke joker4 = new Joke("", "", "", "", "", 4, "");
    System.out.println("Успешно добавихте Joke.");
    return joker4;
}
```

...which i dont think it works...
the above code is located in Joke class.

In my Main class I have:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<Joke> jokes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Joke joker1 = new Joke("kartof23", "alfakartof23@hotmail.com", "Gregory", "Petrov",
                "0899458239", 1, "This is the funniest thing I have ever written!");
        Joke joker2 = new Joke("kalashnikov94", "kalashnikov94@hotmail.com", "Kliment", "Panaiotov",
                "0896482123", 2, "Never got that what i never got!");
        Joke joker3 = new Joke("haralampi45", "haralampi45@abv.bg", "Jordan", "Krumov",
                "0897439457", 3, "That lucky dog was actually a GOD!");

        jokes = new ArrayList<>();
        jokes.add(joker1);
        jokes.add(joker2);
        jokes.add(joker3);

        System.out.println();
        Joke.addJokerToArrayList("kamikadze23", "kamikadze23@gmail.com", "Liubomir", "Kirilov",
                "0874593204", 4, "Не би мирно седяло, не би чудо видяло..."); // <-- I am not sure if this is adding joker4 to the Array jokes.
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `Joke.addJokerToArrayList` could possibly add anything to the `jokes` `ArrayList`, when the body of that method does no such thing, nor does the constructor of `Joke` and you already know how to add objects to a list, as you do with joker1 2 and 3? I'm not trying to be unpleasant, I am trying to understand what misconception you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Joke addJokerToArrayList(String username, String email, String firstName, String lastName,
                                       String phoneNumber, int jokeID, String jokeText) {
    Joke joker4 = new Joke("", "", "", "", "", 4, "");
    System.out.println("Успешно добавихте Joke.");
Main.jokes.add(joker4);////this line would add the joker to the array list
    return joker4;
}
```

Main.jokes.add(joker4);
Main gets the class and since jokes is static it gets the variable and .add(joker4) adds the joke to the array list.

Answer (score 0):

The list `jokes` is not within the `Joke` class. You have to add the returned `Joke` instance to the list.

```
jokes.add(Joke.addJokerToArrayList(....));
```

Also, in you `addJokerToArrayList` method, I don't know why you aren't using the values passed. It must be like,

```
return new Joke(username, email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, jokeId, jokeText);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code review:** this is the refactored working version of the original code:

```java
public static ArrayList<Joke> jokes = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    addJokerToArrayList("kartof23",
            "alfakartof23@hotmail.com",
            "Gregory",
            "Petrov",
            "0899458239",
            1,
            "This is the funniest thing I have ever written!");
    addJokerToArrayList("kalashnikov94",
            "kalashnikov94@hotmail.com",
            "Kliment",
            "Panaiotov",
            "0896482123",
            2,
            "Never got that what i never got!");
    addJokerToArrayList("haralampi45",
            "haralampi45@abv.bg",
            "Jordan",
            "Krumov",
            "0897439457",
            3,
            "That lucky dog was actually a GOD!");

    // output
    jokes.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```java
public static Joke addJokerToArrayList(String username,
                                       String email,
                                       String firstName,
                                       String lastName,
                                       String phoneNumber,
                                       int jokeID,
                                       String jokeText) {
    Joke joke = new Joke(username, email, firstName,
            lastName, phoneNumber, jokeID, jokeText);
    if (jokes.add(joke)) {
        System.out.println("Успешно добавихте Joke.");
    }
    return joke;
}
```

```java
public static class Joke {
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public int jokeID;
    public String jokeText;

    public Joke(String username, String email,
                String firstName, String lastName,
                String phoneNumber, int jokeID, String jokeText) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.jokeID = jokeID;
        this.jokeText = jokeText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Joke{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", jokeID=" + jokeID +
                ", jokeText='" + jokeText + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Успешно добавихте Joke.
Успешно добавихте Joke.
Успешно добавихте Joke.
Joke{username='kartof23', email='alfakartof23@hotmail.com', firstName='Gregory', lastName='Petrov', phoneNumber='0899458239', jokeID=1, jokeText='This is the funniest thing I have ever written!'}
Joke{username='kalashnikov94', email='kalashnikov94@hotmail.com', firstName='Kliment', lastName='Panaiotov', phoneNumber='0896482123', jokeID=2, jokeText='Never got that what i never got!'}
Joke{username='haralampi45', email='haralampi45@abv.bg', firstName='Jordan', lastName='Krumov', phoneNumber='0897439457', jokeID=3, jokeText='That lucky dog was actually a GOD!'}
```